# Kubernetes - ALB Ingress controller - CertificateNotFound

Tags: kubernetes

Ingress controller cannot find the certificate. I get the error `failed to reconcile listeners due to failed to create listener due to CertificateNotFound`

Its a imported LetsEncrypt certificate and describing the certificate using aws cli works.

Here is the error in controller logs:

```
 1 controller.go:217] kubebuilder/controller "msg"="Reconciler error" "error"="failed to reconcile listeners due to failed to create listener due to CertificateNotFound: Certificate 'arn:aws:acm:ap-south-1:1234:certificate/f9a3a88e-481c-4c91-9d55-1234' not found\n\tstatus code: 400, request id: 811dddad-532c-4846-ae10-c69c2f4b4c3b"  "controller"="alb-ingress-controller" "request"={"Namespace":"test-web-dev","Name":"test-ingress-dev"}
```

Comment: How about refer [Issues with certificates](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/917). I think it's related with your issue.

Comment: I looked into it. But even thought they have the same error code, they don't have a solution to the issue

Comment: The cert is imported so it can't be validated. But the cert is working on the test server outside of k8s cluster so its not a cert issue